# Passing command line argument between multiple launch-files

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a launch file `master.launch` that includes `global_config.launch`.
In `master.launch` I define a command line argument using

```
<arg name="config_argument" />
```

and then I include `global_config.launch`

```
<include file="$(find package_name)/launch/global_config.launch" />
```

But  I will need the argument to be available in `global_config.launch`. Is it possible pass the argument from the `master.launch` to the `global_config.launch`?

Thanks to gvdhoorn for linking that question. I changed my launchfiles as follows:
`master.launch`

```
  <arg name="rosbag_name" />  
  <include file="$(find neuromorphic_stereo)/launch/global_config.launch">  
    <arg name="rosbag_name" value="$(arg rosbag_name)" />  
  </include>
```

`global_config.launch`

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="event_publisher" args="$(find neuromorphic_stereo)/rosbag_simulator/$(arg rosbag_name)_merged.bag" required="true" />
```

but now ros tells me

> unused args [rosbag_name] for include
> of global_config.launch

even though I'm actually using it. What am I still doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313634/passing-command-line-argument-between-multiple-launch-files/) by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:
I believe this is a duplicate of (at least) #q199152.

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2019-01-24**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for linking the question gvdhoorn. It indeed seems to be a duplicate. Anyway I run in to problems using the suggested solution. I edited my question. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just have to define the `arg` in both launch files since you could be able to launch `global_config` without the `master`. By definning the `arg` in all the launch files, you still have the possibility to launch them individually (i.e. *standalone*). I would also advise to add a default value to avoid typing arguments if they are not changing too often :

- `master.launch :`

  ```
   <arg name="rosbag_name" default="a_default_bag_file.bag" />  
   <include file="$(find neuromorphic_stereo)/launch/global_config.launch">  
          <arg name="rosbag_name" value="$(arg rosbag_name)" />  
   </include>
  ```
- `global_config.launch` :

  ```
   <arg name="rosbag_name" default="a_default_bag_file.bag" /> 
   <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="event_publisher" args="$(find neuromorphic_stereo)/rosbag_simulator/$(arg rosbag_name)_merged.bag" required="true" />
  ```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2019-01-24**:
Works perfect. Thanks a lot for the hint with the default bag, too :)